# How to set different layouts for different modules in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

How can I set different layouts for different modules in Zend Framework 3 instead of using single one same layout template all around the site?

Comment: Answer is the same as in ZF2...  https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts check Module.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zend Framework - Issue](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html)

> > You may want to alter the layout based on the current
>   module. This requires (a) detecting if the controller matched in
>   routing belongs to this module, and then (b) changing the template of
>   the View Model.
>
> The place to do these actions is in a listener. It should listen
>   either to the “route” event at low (negative) priority, or on the
>   “dispatch” event, at any priority. Typically, you will register this
>   during the bootstrap event.

```html
namespace Content;

class Module
{
    /**
     * @param  \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e The MvcEvent instance
     * @return void
     */
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        // Register a dispatch event
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $app->getEventManager()->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'setLayout'));
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e The MvcEvent instance
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLayout($e)
    {
        $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
        if (false === strpos($controller, __NAMESPACE__)) {
            // not a controller from this module
            return;
        }

        // Set the layout template
        $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTemplate('content/layout');
    }
}
```

The manual says above, but if you want to use these code, you'll need:

```html
// module/Content/config/module.config.php

return [

    /* whatever else */

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_map' => [
            'content/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml' 
        ]
    ]
];
```

Shortly, when all modules initialized(bootstrap) successfully, Zend will call `onBootstrap()` automatically, which bind 'dispatch' event to `setLayout()` method, where the controller name is matched with current module's namespace, and if success, use `setTemplate()` to set layout template.

e.g.

`Module/Namespace: Content,`

`Controller: Content\Controller\MatchMeController,`**(success!)**

`Controller: Other\Controller\DontMatchMeController,`**(fail!)**

But there is a tiny drawback: `setLayout()` use

`strpos(controller, __NAMESPACE__) === false`

to identify current module, but what if I had a `ContentController` in some other module? So use

`strpos(controller, __NAMESPACE__) !== 0`

instead.

----------

[Zend Framework - Issue](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html)

The manual is quite detailed, it also mentions lots of other things like set different layouts for different controllers (or actions).

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between layouts for a particular controller's action by using the following code:

```
// A controller's action method that uses an alternative
// layout template.
public function indexAction() 
{
  //...

  // Use the Layout plugin to access the ViewModel
  // object associated with layout template.
  $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/layout2');

  //...
}
```

> In addition to the `Layout` controller plugin, there is the `Layout` view
>   helper which provides the same capabilities. With the Layout view
>   helper, you can, for example, switch layout from the "static" page
>   which has no specific controller action.

**Setting Layout for All Actions of a Controller**

If all action methods of a controller class need to use the same alternative layout, you can override the `onDispatch()` method of the `AbstractActionController` class and call the `setTemplate()` method there, as shown in the example below:

```
// Add this alias in the beginning of the controller file
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

// ...

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController 
{
  /** 
   * We override the parent class' onDispatch() method to
   * set an alternative layout for all actions in this controller.
   */
  public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) 
  {
    // Call the base class' onDispatch() first and grab the response
    $response = parent::onDispatch($e);        

    // Set alternative layout
    $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/layout2');                

    // Return the response
    return $response;
  }
}
```

[**Reference**](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Page_Appearance_and_Layout/Switching_between_Layouts.html)