# change layout in different module on zf3

Tags: layout, zend-framework3

while i change layout in different mudule on zf3, there is a error caused.

Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: Route with name "" not found in /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-router/src/Http/TreeRouteStack.php:354 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Helper/Url.php(106): Zend\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->assemble(Array, Array) #1 [internal function]: Zend\View\Helper\Url->__invoke('/passport') #2 /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(397): call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\View\Helper\Url), Array) #3 /mnt/shared/zf3.local/module/Passport/view/layout/layout.phtml(42): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('url', Array) #4 /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(505): include('/mnt/shared/zf3...') #5 /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(207): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render() #6 /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(105): Zend\View\View->render(O in /mnt/shared/zf3.local/vendor/zendframework/zend-router/src/Http/TreeRouteStack.php on line 354

i have no idea to solve this problem.

i used the tutorial :
[How to set different layouts for different modules in Zend Framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181792/how-to-set-different-layouts-for-different-modules-in-zend-framework-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check implementation or just use this module

[Change layout per module](https://github.com/tasmaniski/zend-layout-change)